# Transform an XML structure into an TABLE TR TD with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xsd, xslt-1.0

I have a problem with transforming an XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ceva.xsl"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<reports>
    <report_head>
        <value>product_id</value>
        <value>product_name</value>
    </report_head>
    <report_data>
        <value>1</value>
        <value>PRODUCT NAME NO 43</value>
    </report_data>
    <report_data>
        <value>2</value>
        <value>PRODUCT NAME NO 56</value>
    </report_data>
    <report_data>
        <value>3</value>
        <value>PRODUCT NAME NO 65</value>
    </report_data>
</reports>
```

into a table like

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>product_id</td>
        <td>product_name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>PRODUCT NAME NO 43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>PRODUCT NAME NO 56</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>PRODUCT NAME NO 65</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and here is the XSL I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
        <body>
        <h2>Transform a table</h2>

        <!--
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="reports/report_head/value">
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>


            <xsl:for-each select="reports/report_data/value">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
            </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
        -->

        <table border="1">
            <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </tr>
        </table>

        </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--

    <xsl:template match="value">

        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
        </tr>

    </xsl:template>
    </table>
    -->

    <xsl:template match="value">
        <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but wait, there is more, I don't know how many columns there are. A typical report may have like 10 columns, but it could have 20, 30+, so the xslt must do this dynamically.

I have tried `for-each`, and someone suggested using a `template`, but I don't got any results. What do I have to do now?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this (http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog) little tool for rapid prototyping (see http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp for more).
Think this does the job, if I understood you right:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>Transform a table</h2>

    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="reports/report_head/value">
          <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="reports/report_data">
      <tr> 
        <xsl:for-each select="./value">
          <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>

  </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Edit #1: fix missplaced `</tr>`

It produces this table ...

```
product_id  product_name 
1           PRODUCT NAME NO 43 
2           PRODUCT NAME NO 56 
3           PRODUCT NAME NO 65
```

... and worked with more columns too.

Hope that helps! Cheers

Comment: Nice variant, however there is a bug that causes two `<tr>` inside each other. I would move the last `</tr>` just below the first `</xsl:for-each>` to fix this.

Your variant allows for using the `<th>` for the headers, which is nice.

Comment: so witch is the better, the TEMPLATE or the FOR-EACH ? i cannot tell, and one more thing `<xsl:for-each select="./value">` what is "./" ???

Comment: `./value` is the same as `value`; `./` means *current path*

Answer (score 3):

This seemed to work for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
        <body>
        <h2>Transform a table</h2>

        <table border="1">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </table>

        </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="report_data | report_head">
        <tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="value">
        <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: i don't imagine how all of those two examples works and witch is the best, thank you! I understand this, but not quite 100% yet.